# I replaced notepad with atom, can't open files with spaces?

Tags: windows, notepad, atom-editor

I'm trying out different editors to possibly replace notepad with, something light but with modern editing features (such as multiple cursors). I've used Notepad3 for the longest time, I don't like Notepad++, and now trying Atom. I like the VSCode editing experience so I was expecting something similar.

I did the replacement through the registry like usual:

```
[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\notepad.exe]
"Debugger"="\"C:\\Program Files\\Atom\\atom.exe\""
```

(don't mind the path, I wanted a system level install)

It works for the most part, however I noticed it has problems with files containing spaces. It treats each blob as a separate file name. For example, opening a file with this path through Windows Explorer:

```
C:\Program Files\Atom\test file.txt
```

Opens atom with the following open:

```
C:\Program
C:\WINDOWS\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE
C:\Program Files\Atom\Files\Atom\test
C:\Program Files\Atom\file.txt
```

[image]

This obviously isn't right. Opening from command line works fine like you would expect.

Is there some setting I could use to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into it, it looks like the default shortcut for text files to open notepad does not quote the file path, apparently notepad allows for this and is able to open the file as expected. So rather than having one argument containing the path, arguments are split up using usual argument parsing rules. I have a couple of options here.

I could update the registry values to quote the file name argument:

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\open\command]
[image]

Drawback is I would have to do this for all extensions that use notepad that also doesn't quote.

---

Otherwise, I could create a program or script to read all the arguments and concatenate them into a single argument, then launch atom with the constructed path.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,* delims= " %%a in ("%*") do start "Atom" atom "%%b"
```

Note: Learned the hard way that you should always provide a title to the start command in the first argument, to ensure that the process to be run is not mistaken for the title. Caused some bad fork bombs on my machine that took some time to figure out.

---

edit: After using this for a while, this was just not reliable enough. For a quick, general solution, it didn't work in general. And after fiddling around with the registry to update all values that invoked notepad to quote the args, still didn't quite work the way I wanted.

Ideally, there'd be a simple utility app that would collects the arguments and passes it to the preferred app in the standard way. I could code it myself, but opted to use something specific for this situation. This just inserts itself to replace notepad calls and forwards to the configured replacement. It might be something I revisit one day.

https://www.binaryfortress.com/NotepadReplacer/

Comment: Having used notepad3 for so long, I wondered why it needed a special command line argument in its shortcut. `"C:\Program Files\Notepad3\Notepad3.exe" /z` It was probably for this reason.

Comment: AFAIK a program in DOS/Windows is executed by passing the entire command line as a single value. Let's take a C program for example.  Before the Windows system calls `main()`, it calls `_setargv()` to parse the command line into the standard C `argc` and `argv[]` arguments that it passes to the `main()` function of the program. The program can provide its own `_setargv()`, giving it complete control over what syntax to impose on the command line. For comparison: in \*nix any program gets an array, not a string. You type a string in a shell and the shell splits it and creates an array. (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) My point is, if you're right, it means at least one editor (notepad or atom) uses a custom `_setargv()`.

Comment: Notepad is a very ancient app. Wouldn't surprise me if it still contained a large majority of the original code. And being an old ancient app, it likely used some winapis directly to do much of its functionality, including handling command args. Apis like `GetCommandLineA/W` to get the full command line as a string and easily grab the path. And considering this was common to support unquoted arguments, seems plausible. Atom on the other hand is based on electron which is node.js-based so it will certainly use the standard arg parsing.